# Drawing Unconnected 3D Arc in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to draw a 3-dimensional half circle arc in PGFPlots using a parametric equation. This is the relevant code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ticks=none,
    view = {135}{20},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=0, zmax=1,
    unit vector ratio = 1 1 1,
]
\addplot3[domain=-0.25*pi:0.75*pi,red]
({0.5*cos(deg(x))},{0.5*sin(deg(x))},{0.5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It doesn't look how I want it to, however. I do not want the ends of the arc to be connected. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Hi @dexteritas, thanks for the tip! Does this look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ticks=none,
view={135}{20},
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$z$,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
%unit vector ratio = 1 1 1,
axis equal,
scale mode=none,
trig format plots=rad,
]
\addplot3[domain=-0.25*pi:0.75*pi, red, samples y=1]({0.5*cos(x)},{0.5*sin(x)},{0.5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D graph wit semi circle]

From manual p. 125

> If you use `\addplot3` expression, `mesh/rows` and `mesh/cols` are computed
> from the values samples and `samples y`. By default, `\addplot3`
> expression always samples a mesh. If you want it to sample a line, set
> `samples y=1` (or, equivalently, `y domain=0:0`).

Comment: Thank you! `samples y=1` did the trick. Thanks also for your other minor improvements of my code.